# how to Modify a form using php sessions

Tags: php, session

I m trying to modify a form using sessions. I m trying an application where the user login using username and password.After login home page displays for a particular user where he can add details and modify the details.I have a problem when modifying the details. The details doesnt get displayed to edit the details.The value entered from add form doesnt display in the text box of modify. How can i display the details?

here is the code

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
mysql_query("UPDATE cvformat SET surname='".$_POST['surname']."', mname='".$_POST['mname']."',pid='".$_POST['pid']."',dob='".$_POST['dob']."',city='".$_POST['city']."',region='".$_POST['region']."', country='".$_POST['country']."', diocese='".$_POST['diocese']."',nationality='".$_POST['nationality']."',fname='".$_POST['fname']."',mothername='".$_POST['mothername']."', edate='".$_POST['edate']."',city2='".$_POST['city2']."',region2='".$_POST['region2']."',country2='".$_POST['country2']."',datef='".$_POST['datef']."', dateo='".$_POST['dateo']."', city3='".$_POST['city3']."',region3='".$_POST['region3']."',country3='".$_POST['country3']."',bishop='".$_POST['bishop']."',tedate='".$_POST['tedate']."',city4='".$_POST['city4']."',region4='".$_POST['region4']."', country4='".$_POST['country4']."', tdirector='".$_POST['tdirector']."',sof='".$_POST['sof']."',decreefv='".$_POST['decreefv']."',fvdate='".$_POST['fvdate']."',city5='".$_POST['city5']."',region5='".$_POST['region5']."', country5='".$_POST['country5']."', cres='".$_POST['cres']."', q1='".$_POST['q1']."',s1='".$_POST['s1']."',y1='".$_POST['y1']."',p1='".$_POST['p1']."',q2='".$_POST['q2']."',s2='".$_POST['s2']."', y2='".$_POST['y2']."', p2='".$_POST['p2']."', q3='".$_POST['q3']."',s3='".$_POST['s3']."',y3='".$_POST['y3']."', p3='".$_POST['p3']."',ca='".$_POST['ca']."',sp='".$_POST['sp']."' where name='".$_SESSION['name']."'")  or die(mysql_error()); 
  };
  $myData= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cvformat where name='".$_SESSION['name']."'")or die(mysql_error());



while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($myData)) 
{ 
?>
    <h4 align="right" style="margin-right:170px;">Welcome <?=$_SESSION['name'];?>!<a href="logout.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Logout</a></h4>
<div id="header" align="center"><img src="images/header.png" alt="" /></div>
    <form name="XIForm" id="XIForm" method="POST" action="pdf/pdf1.php">
<table border="0px" cellspacing="0px" cellspacing="10px" align="center" width="700px">



<tr>
<td style="width:200px;"><div class="label"><b >Surname,Name:</b></div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" style="width:250px; padding:5px; value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) { echo $record['surname']; } ?>">
```

}
how can i display the value in textbox using sessions? Please help me out with this

Comment: No need to check `$_SESSION['name']`. Because you already get `$record['surname']` from `while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($myData))` So direct write `value=<?PHP echo $record['surname'];?>`

Comment: i have tried the same thing..I m not getting it

Comment: Use `print_r($record)` after `while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($myData)) { ` and check that you get `surname` in `$record` in `while` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($myData)) 
{ 
?>
<h4 align="right" style="margin-right:170px;">Welcome <?php echo $record['name'];?>!<a href="logout.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Logout</a></h4>
<div id="header" align="center"><img src="images/header.png" alt="" /></div>
<form name="XIForm" id="XIForm" method="POST" action="pdf/pdf1.php">
<table border="0px" cellspacing="0px" cellspacing="10px" align="center" width="700px">



<tr>
<td style="width:200px;"><div class="label"><b >Surname,Name:</b></div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" style="width:250px; padding:5px; value="<?php echo $record['surname']; ?>">

<?PHP } ?>
```

Comment: use `echo mysql_num_rows($myData);` before `while` to show how many row you fetch from table.

Comment: Then you will definitely get detail from `cvformat` table. Use `print_r($record)` show what u get from table.

Comment: it displays.. but how to display in particular text box

Comment: But inside the textbox it doesnt display

Comment: Make sour fetched `$record` `surname` column name same as database table column name.

Comment: it is the same name as column name

Comment: ohkkk!! what is solution you get?

Comment: there was no values in the db

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `<?php  ?>` tags. try this-

```
<input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" style="width:250px; padding:5px; value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) { echo $record['surname']; } ?>">
```

and another tag should be there before while loop ends.

Comment: where should i add this?